# Visual Studio Adds extra closing bracket when autofilling closing HTML tags

Tags: razor, visual-studio-2017, resharper-2017

I recently upgraded from Visual Studio 2015 to 2017, with ReSharper running in both. Now, when working with Razor (.cshtml) views, if I type an opening tag (e.g. `<div>`), VS automatically adds the closing tag (i.e. `</div>`), but also puts in an extra copy of the closing brace from the opening tag so I end up with `<div>></div>`.

It's a minor hassle, and less of one than turning off AutoComplete for closing tags, but I'd like to know if anyone else has had this problem and which one of these infinite settings I would need to change to correct that behavior.